# Angularjs filters when used in combination with each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok so I was watching [a YouTube video about Angularjs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2okVLCrqgE&t=2h14m18s) and on one of the lines of code, they were using two filters. It went something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in event.events | orderBy: 'date' | limitTo: '2'" ...>
```

My only question is on the order of operations here. This question is NOT about the difference between sorting and then limiting the list of items versus limiting the items first and then sorting them. For further clarification, the question is more about **how angular implements this and whether it does any optimization**, so one can decide how to use these filters more effectively. It seems that sorting a list of 100 and then cutting it down to two elements is extremely inefficient when you could (maybe outside of angular or with a custom filter) find the most recent items, but stop looking when you get to the number of items you want displayed.

In angular's default behavior with the above code, is the entire list of events sorted by date before being cut down to two or does angular do some internal optimization to make this more efficient? Or would one have to make a custom filter to achieve this optimization?

Comment: Just to clarify, your question is about how angular achieves this under the hood?  It's about angular's implementation and not necessarily about how to use this in your code?

Comment: Yeah I understand how to use the filters. The question is more about how angular implements this so I can use this more effectively. Because sorting a list of 100 and then cutting it down to two elements seems extremely inefficient when you could (maybe outside of angular or with a custom filter) find the most recent items, but stop looking when you get to the amount of items you want displayed.

Comment: Ok.  You should probably edit your knowledge into your question.  And based on some of the answers you've gotten, others feel you are confused about the fact that `sort --> limit` is different than `limit-->sort`.  It's not clear that your question is about whether angular does any sorting optimizations since it knows it will later limit.

Comment: Ok yeah just edited the question and I am certainly not confused on sort to limit versus limit to sort. Limit to sort will most of the time return an answer that does not have the item with the most recent date whereas sort to limit does. I shall add this in the question as well lol.

Comment: Ok that's a pretty good edit.  I made some changes that (IMO) make your post more readable and less intimidating.

Comment: No! taking away my freedom of speech!!! Lol jk. But why don't you just throw some style sheets on it while you're at it? You know what? Screw it! Let's just make a website dedicated to this one question, hire the best designers and spend an excessive amount of money on this new classy website! Dude you like pimped out my question thanks haha.

Comment: No problem.  That's what this community is all about.  Ideally every post gets this kind of care from the author or other passersby.  Just in the future, try to make your question as clear as you can from the start.  And thank you for caring and actually editing your question when asked.  And Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next filter will be applied to the result of another filter. This is called "chaining".

**EDIT**

There's no optimization, the filter execution gets the subset from the previous filter and then applies its filter logic. If you want optimization, you should consider implementing a custom filter that fits your needs.

Comment: That's so sad... Oh well, good thing I was thinking when I saw that lol. Will keep this in mind next time I'm ordering a list =D